# How to make a large title in the navigation controller half light, half bold?

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I want to make my `title` look like this (1st picture) (day and month are bold (default), year has a light font-weight)
[designer's sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFSVH.png)

How do I make different styles of font weight in the `title` in UIKit w/o using Storyboard?
Or may be it is impossible?

I was thinking about creating two `UILabel` with different styles, but then how do I put them in the `title`?

Answer (score 0):

Install a `UILabel` in the navigation item's `titleView` property.

Install an `NSAttributedString` into the label's `attributedText` property. An attributed string can contain text with different styling applied to different parts, like the example you show.

Comment: When I do this, largeTitle becomes usual navigation controller. Even `navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always` does not help

Answer (score 0):

```
 if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {

            let frame = CGRect(x: navigationBar.center.x-(navigationBar.center.x/3), y: 0, width: navigationBar.frame.width/2, height: navigationBar.frame.height)
            let myMutableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "November 5, 2021", attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)])
            myMutableString.setAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20),
                                                   NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black],
                                                  range: NSMakeRange(0, 11))
            let lbl = UILabel(frame: frame)
            lbl.attributedText = myMutableString
            navigationBar.addSubview(lbl)
  }
```

you can set the center constraints according to your need :)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have additional question: is it possible to keep largeTitle's style? (I mean 'leading', fontSize '36', paddings). Or I have to make it on my own?

Comment: you can set your whatever largeTitle style in myMutableString.setAttributes.

Comment: If you need any help anytime then ping me. i’ll provide you best possible solution.